# Let $f({x\over x+1})=x^2$. Find $f(x)$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}$ fulfill $f({x\over x+1})=x^2$. Find $f(x)$.

I guess there is a rule or a claim I should be using but I can't think o any. It was given in an exercise about infimum\supremum (It includes the material of the very beginning, not derivatives and etc)but I can't see how it relates. Hints are preferred since I really do want to get there on my own. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: It could as well be a precedent of what we would be doing later on... So I can't really tell what I can and cannot use...

Comment: Let $y=\frac{x}{x+1}$.  
Then $y=1-\frac{1}{x+1}\iff 1-y=\frac{1}{x+1}\iff x=\frac{1}{1-y}-1=\frac{y}{1-y}$. 

$f(y)=\left(\frac{y}{1-y}\right)^2, \forall y\in\mathbb R, y\neq 1$.

Comment: $1$ is not in the domain of $f$ because $\frac x{x+1} \neq 1$ for all $x.$

Comment: @abel It's written that the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb R$, so $f(1)$ exists, we simply don't know what it is.

Comment: @user314, then, how can you find $f(1)?$ is not finding $f(x)$ include finding $f(1)?$

Comment: @abel The problem is thus flawed in that we can't find the full function $f(x)$, only the values of it at all points not equal to $1$. We don't know what $f(1)$ is, but we do know that $f(1)\in\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $y=\frac{x}{x+1}$.
Then $y=1-\frac{1}{x+1}\iff 1-y=\frac{1}{x+1}\iff x=\frac{1}{1-y}-1=\frac{y}{1-y}$.

$$f(y)=\left(\frac{y}{1-y}\right)^2, \forall y\in\mathbb R, y\neq 1$$

Seemingly $f(x)$ is undefined at $x=1$, since $\frac{x}{x+1}\neq 1,\forall x\in\mathbb R$.

We know that $f(1)$ exists, since the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb R$.

We also know that $f(1)\in\mathbb R$, since the codomain of $f$ is $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Or we can claim that the problem never said that the function had to be continuous, and just define $f(1) = 42$ or something. It is supposed to be a function from the whole of $\Bbb R$, after all.

Comment: I am having trouble finding $f(x)$... I know it is $f({y\over 1-y})$ but I can't seem to use $f(y)$...

Comment: @Meit The $x$ in $f(x)$ is just an arbitrary symbol for a real number. The $y$ in $f(y)$ is too just an arbitrary symbol for any real number (it just can't be $1$) and so saying $f(y)$ is the same as saying $f(x), x\neq 1$. So we know the function $f$ at all real points except at $x=1$, which we know nothing about, only that $f(1)$ exists, since the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I feel really stupid right now...
Time to go to sleep. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $g(x) = \frac{x}{x+1}$ and $h(x) = x^2$. Then you have $f(g(x)) = h(x)$, that is, writing it as compositions, $f \circ g = h$. If we can find an inverse for $g$, we get $f = h \circ g^{-1}$. Going back to our particular case, $f(x) = (g^{-1}(x))^2$. If you can find an inverse for $g$, you're done.

Comment: +1. This is a nice "high-level" way of looking at the problem, which generalizes nicely to other problems. (The examples that come to mind come from complex analysis, where such pre- and/or post-compositions can turn seemingly difficult inequalities into simple applications of the Schwarz lemma.)